# NoSuchElementException in mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, stringtokenizer

I am new to map reduce getting NoSuchElementException, please help.

input file container below text :

```
this is a hadoop program
i am writing it for first time
```

Mapper class :

```
public class Mappers extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, IntWritable>{
    private Text word = new Text();
    private IntWritable singleWordCount = new IntWritable();
    private IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<IntWritable, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
         StringTokenizer wordList = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
         while (wordList.hasMoreTokens()) {
             int wordSize = wordList.nextToken().length();
             singleWordCount.set(wordSize);
             if(word != null && wordList != null && wordList.nextToken() != null){
                 word.set(wordList.nextToken());
                 output.collect(singleWordCount, one);
             }
        }
    }

}
```

[This is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ska9N.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `wordList.nextToken()` three times in the loop for every iteration. Every time you call it `StringTokenizer`will return the next token, which will cause the exception when your program hits the word `first` in your text, because you retrieve `first` then `time` and then try to retrieve the next word, which doesn't exist, causing the exception.

What you need to do is retrieve it once in every iteration and store it in a variable. Or if you really need to retrieve two words in one iteration always call `hasMoreTokens()` to check if there actually is another word to process before you actually call `nextToken()`.